# How do I crop an image after finding the contours with opencv java?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to crop out a picture of a form. I used edge detection and I found the contours using this method :

```
    Mat frameImg = tess.bufferedImageToMat(image);
    frameImg = this.doCanny(frameImg);
    frameImg = this.doBackgroundRemoval(frameImg);
    frameImg = this.doFindContours(frameImg);

public Mat doFindContours(final Mat src) {

Mat dst = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), src.type());
src.copyTo(dst);

Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

final List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
final Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(dst, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Rect boundRect;
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

return dst;
```

}

How should I use the contours to crop out my image?

Comment: Fill on mask, then bitwise

Comment: Why would we have to fill the contours? I thought we just take the contour points and find the position of where the form is, then crop the original image with that information.

Comment: Sorry, I use mask to get the contour regions. If to crop, then get the submat with  boundingrect of the specific contour.

Comment: Ahh yes. I guess my question should be how would I get the specific contour?